# Having trouble by adding txt files to .EXE using Auto-Py-To-Exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller, py2exe

I've been using auto py to exe to convert my program into an exe file. however, I can't make it open the txt files that the program uses.

My program looks like this:

```
With open ("text.txt", "r") as file:
    """does something"""
```

and every time I run the .exe file I get this error:

```
No such file or directory: 'text.txt'
```

I am using the -add-data commando, though. So, for what I can see in the library manual, it should work. I had the same problem with PyInstaller. any help?

Comment: Hi David, welcome to Stack Overflow. To help others help you, it's useful to include a minimal reproducible example of the issue you are trying to solve. Since this is with auto-py-to-exe, it would be useful to see the "current command" that auto-py-to-exe is building for you.

Comment: Also note that auto-py-to-exe uses PyInstaller under the hood, and there are many questions on SO about including data files with PyInstaller. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile/13790741

Answer (score 0):

Have updated previous answer  , manually place the **txt** file in the output folder generated

```
import os
import sys


try:
    with open(os.path.join(sys.path[0], "text.txt"), "r") as f:
        print(f.read())
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Thanks! However, now what I get is: No such file or directory: './text.txt'

Comment: have u place this file in the exe folder

Comment: yes, I have. I dont know why this could be happening honestly.

Comment: can u try with the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I found that when you using auto-py-to-exe create --onefile exe. When the exe file runs, it creates a folder in C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Temp and runs it. You can using `print(str(Path(__file__).parent.absolute()))` to check

Answer (score 0):

I used to fix that problem with this:-

```
api_key = ""

try:
    with open(os.path.join(sys.path[2], "api_key.txt"), "r") as file:
    api_key += file.read()
file.close()
except FileNotFoundError:
    with open(os.path.join(sys.path[0], "api_key.txt"), "r") as file:
        api_key += file.read()
        file.close()
```